# How to fix following FileNotFoundException while uploading image to a folder in JavaEE?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, netbeans, glassfish

**Solved it myself - solution is below**

I am trying to upload image into server directory (not as byte in db) since i don't want to store image into MySQL. But, I am not getting the image upload as i want to and having FileNotFoundException in server log. What is wrong in my servlet code below for file upload. Is it getRealPath("") that is causing the problem? If yes What is the solution or alternative for it. If it is not the reason for what i am getting now, please help me know my mistake.
Is this the right way for my servlet version? I think i have servlet api 3.0 or above. please point me if i am wrong.

**Platform i am using**
Netbeans 8.0.2 installed to C:\Program Files
Glassfish 4.1 extracted to G:\glassfish4\
Project location E:\NetBeansProjects

**here is my glassfish server log**

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: G:\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\generated\jsp\e-Shop\E:\NetBeansProjects\e-Shop\build\web\img\products\Untitled.png (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

**here is part of my upload code from my servlet**

```
else if (userPath.contains("/admin/uploadCategory")){

            String SAVE_DIR = "/img/categories";

            // gets absolute path of the web application
            String appPath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("");
            // constructs path of the directory to save uploaded file
            String savePath = appPath + File.separator + SAVE_DIR;


            // creates the save directory if it does not exists
        File fileSaveDir = new File(savePath);
        if (!fileSaveDir.exists()) {
            fileSaveDir.mkdir();
        }

        for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
            String fileName = extractFileName(part);
            part.write(savePath + File.separator + fileName);
        }

        request.setAttribute("message", "Upload has been done successfully!");
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/admin/message.jsp").forward(
                request, response);

        }
        else if (userPath.contains("/admin/uploadProduct")){

            String SAVE_DIR = "/img/products";

            // gets absolute path of the web application
            String appPath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("");
            // constructs path of the directory to save uploaded file
            String savePath = appPath + File.separator + SAVE_DIR;


            // creates the save directory if it does not exists
            File fileSaveDir = new File(savePath);
            if (!fileSaveDir.exists()) {
                fileSaveDir.mkdir();
            }

            for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
                String fileName = extractFileName(part);
                part.write(savePath + File.separator + fileName);
            }

        request.setAttribute("message", "Upload has been done successfully!");
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/admin/message.jsp").forward(
                request, response);

        }
```

Comment: Somehow you got both `g` an `e` drives in your path. Obviously it can only be one of them.

Comment: the server is installed in G drive..  the project directory is on E drive. I don't think it is the case.

Comment: That may be the case, but no single path can contain two drives, so it is the case.

Comment: Ok. Then why Netbeans provided such feature to change project directory? Please help me understand this a bit. Will it works if i move the project to g:?  Isn't there a way to get relative path from project directory instead of getRealPath.

Comment: @developerwjk You were wrong i made it work with same platform settings. Glassfish on G:   Netbeans Project directory on E: and Netbeans IDE on c: . You need to update yourself. I made it work using inputstream..

Comment: So you're saying you can have a file in a path like `G:\whatever\E:\something\`?

Comment: @developerwjk. its not path. the IDE was showing 2 lines which seems like 1 line so you got confused. The image file is uploaded to E:\NetBeansProjects\e-Shop\build\web\img\products\Untitled.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it myself this way

```
else if (userPath.contains("/admin/uploadProduct")){
            String fileName="";
            String SAVE_DIR = "/img/products";

            try {
                Part filePart = request.getPart("file");
                fileName = getFileName(filePart);
                String applicationPath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("");
                String basePath = applicationPath + File.separator + SAVE_DIR + File.separator;
                InputStream inputStream = null;
                OutputStream outputStream = null;
                try {
                    File outputFilePath = new File(basePath + fileName);
                    inputStream = filePart.getInputStream();
                    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFilePath);
                    int read = 0;
                    final byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                    while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1){
                        outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
                    }

                }catch (Exception e){
                e.toString();
                fileName = "";
                }finally {
                    if (outputStream != null){
                        outputStream.close();
                    }
                    if (inputStream != null){
                        inputStream.close();
                    }
                }

            }catch (Exception e){
                e.toString();
                fileName = "";
            }
            //return fileName;





        }
```